# c++ How can I read values from a .csv file and store them in a vector?

Tags: c++, csv, vector

I use Code::Blocks on Windows 7 to make little .exe from .cpp files, and I am a beginner (sorry!)

**Here's today's problem:**

I have a .csv file containing long integers (from 0 to 2^16) separated by semicolons and listed as a series of horizontal lines.

I will make a simple example here, but in reality the file can be up to 2Go big.

Let's say my file  `wall.csv` appears like this in a text editor such as `Notepad++`:

```
350;3240;2292;33364;3206;266;290

362;314;244;2726;24342;2362;310

392;326;248;2546;2438;228;314

378;334;274;2842;308;3232;356
```

Strangely enough, it appears like this in the windows `notepad`

```
350;3240;2292;33364;3206;266;290
362;314;244;2726;24342;2362;310
392;326;248;2546;2438;228;314
378;334;274;2842;308;3232;356
```

Anyway,

let's say that I will know and will declare in 3 `float` variables the amount of columns, the amount of lines, and a value from the file.

```
int col = 7;   // amount of columns
int lines = 4; // amount of lines
float x = 0;     // a variable that will contain a value from the file
```

**I want:**

1. to create a `vector <float> myValues`
2. do `myValues.push_back(x)` with each value from the **1st line of the csv**
3. do `myValues.push_back(x)` with each value from the **2nd line of the csv**
4. do `myValues.push_back(x)` with each value from the **3rd line ...etc.**

*until the file has been entirely stored in the vector myValues.*

**My problem:**

I don't know how to successively assign to the variable `x` the values present in the csv file.

How should I do that?

---

OK this code works (rather slowly but ok!):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int col = 1221;   // amount of columns
int lines = 914; // amount of lines
int x = 0;     // a variable that will contain a value from the file

vector <int> myValues;

int main() {

    ifstream ifs ("walls.tif.csv");

    char dummy;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines; ++i){
        for (int i = 0; i < col; ++i){
            ifs >> x;
            myValues.push_back(x);
            // So the dummy won't eat digits
            if (i < (col - 1))
                ifs >> dummy;
        }
    }
    float A = 0;
    float B = col*lines;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < myValues.size(); ++i){

        float C = 100*(A/B);
        A++;
        // display progress and successive x values
        cout << C << "% accomplished, pix = " << myValues[i] <<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the C++ Standard Template Library's input operations.

Make a dummy character variable to eat up semicolons, then cin numbers into your x variable like so:

```
char dummy;
for (int i = 0; i < lines; ++i){
    for (int i = 0; i < col; ++i){
        cin >> x;
        myValues.push_back(x);
        // So the dummy won't eat digits
        if (i < (col - 1))
            cin >> dummy;
    }
}
```

To do it this way, you can redirect your csv file to be input from the command line like so:

```
yourExecutable.exe < yourFile.csv
```

To loop through a vector that is filled with data:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < myVector.size(); ++i){
    cout << myVector[i];
}
```

Above, the size_t type is defined by the STL library and is used to suppress an error.

If you want to use the values only once, removing them from the container as they are used, you're better off using the std::queue container. This way, you look at the front element using front() and remove it using pop().

Comment: dummy will eat digits also starting from second line

Comment: Good call, I fixed it above

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand this: `yourExecutable.exe < yourFile.csv` how do you use it?

Comment: Should I use `ifstream ifs ("myFile.csv")` ?

Comment: Yes, that should work. And then everywhere that "cin" is used above, you would replace it with "ifs".

Comment: Something's wrong, I think the code works but `cout<<myValues.front();`shows only 0's, I updated the code above, I don't really get what's going on...

Comment: SORRY! the name of the csv was wrong. It is now correct and the console returns nothing at all, anything wrong in the code I updated above? Thanks!

Comment: Right now, you're using your vector like a queue. Instead, you should loop through the vector using indices. See my edit above for an example

Comment: that's much better since it goes fast. But I still have the problem that you can see in my updated post: the vector seems to contain only the fist value of the .csv file : 350, repeated.

Comment: Try making your dummy var a char rather than int. That should help, but it probably won't completely fix your problem just yet.

Comment: Make sure that your col variable has the correct number of columns

Comment: Thanks! changing to `char` definitely solved something! It was my mistake.

Comment: This has a nested for loop, where both loops are using `i` This will definitely cause issues.

Answer (score 3):

Put the text data into a `stringstream` and use `std::getline`.

It takes an optional third parameter which is the `"end-of-line"` character, but you can use `;` instead of a real `end of line`.

Call 
`while (std::getline(ss, str, ';')) {..}`

and each loop puts the text in `std::string`.

Then you will need to convert to a number data type and push into a vector but this will get you started.

Also, why do you use `floats` for the number of columns and lines?

They are integer values.

Comment: You are right, they are integers. However I will need to divide them by 2^16 later so I thought it would be better to store them as float from the beginning.

Comment: Why do you need to divide the column and line values by so much?

Comment: Because these integers are in fact greyscale 16bit raw image values

Comment: But float col, float lines are not.